# Extend My Models

Tags: c#, wpf, object, mvvm, model

I am working on a `WPF MVVM` framework

I have a `ItemType` Model

```
public class ItemType
{
    public long ItemTypeID { get; set; }
    public long ItemCategoryID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and other `ItemCategory` Model

```
public class ItemCategory
{
    public long ItemCategoryID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to Bind `ItemType` to a data grid, But I don't want to show `ItemCategoryID`. I want to show `ItemCategory.Name`

How can this be done without changing my original class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what MVVM uses the ViewModel for.

Do not modify the Model but instead create ViewModel classes that are structured according to the needs of the View. that is where you would leave out the properties you don't want.

**EDIT**

Here is a way of doing that:

```
public class ItemTypeViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            if (_name != value)
            {
                _name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
    }

    private string category;
    public string Category
    {
        get { return category; }
        set
        {
            if (category != value)
            {
                category = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Category");
            }
        }
    }

    public static ItemTypeViewModel FromModel(ItemType model)
    {
        var itemTypeViewModel = 
            new ItemTypeViewModel 
            {
                Name = model.Name,
                Category = categories[model.CategoryID].Name;
            };
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var p = PropertyChanged;
        if (p != null)
        {
            p(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}

public class ItemTypesViewModel : ObservableCollection<ItemTypesViewModel>
{
    private ObservableCollection<ItemTypeViewModel> _collection;

    public ObservableCollection<ItemTypeViewModel> Collection
    {
        get { return _collection; }
        set
        {
            if (_collection != value)
            {
                _collection = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Collection"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Use the static method to create instances of the `ItemTypeViewModel` for each ItemType in the model. Put them all in the 'Collection' property of the `ItemTypeSViewModel`.

Bind the DataGrid to the Collection.

I 'removed' the relation that exists in your model between ItemType and ItemCategory from my ViewModel. This is just one way of handling such a construction. Instead you could create a ViewModel class for the ItemCategory too and have a reference in the ItemTypeViewModel class to an instance of the ItemCategoryViewModel class.

Note that this is just one way of handling this. You could solve this problem in some other ways too. Also: you will need to provide a transformation from the ViewModel classes back to the Model as well.

A final bit of advise: if this is new to you start reading/watching tutorials on MVVM: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267903/learning-mvvm-for-wpf

Comment: I was using one view model per view and fetching the data from the database. As ObserableCollection<Model> and binding them to my view grid. what change should i make?

Comment: Create a class containing the properties and commands that you need in the user interface (this is a ViewModel class, it should implement INotifyPropertyChanged). after loading model classes from the database  load the ViewModel class with data from these models) Bind the grid to the ViemModel class. I'll add an example to my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have solved the problem by use a Repository and binding the ItemCategory object to each ItemType now and binding the ItemType to the datagrid and adding columb to with binding path it ItemCategory.Name did solve the problem :)

Answer (score 2):

The answer provided by both guys are perfectly valid and fit your needs, as much as I understood your question.  The basic idea is:

@Amani:

```
//check if the query fits your needs
var temp = from i in categoryList
                   from it in itemList
                   where i.ItemCategoryID == it.ItemCategoryID 
                   select new { i, it };
```

Make a cross query to generate a **new composed type**, which can be

```
public class ItemTypeViewModel
{
    public long ItemTypeID { get; set; }
    public string ItemCategoryName { get; set; }
    public string ItemTypeName { get; set; }
}
```

this is according to MVVM patter guideline responded by @Erno. Use a collection of `ItemTypeViewModel` object to bind them to your view.

Hope this helps.

Regards.

Comment: Thanks now i understand i have a ItemTypeViewModel which i use bind to a view name ItemTypeView where i enter the ItemType what should i name the viewmodel where i keep the collection of object?

Comment: The properties of this class, may be also implementing INotifyPropertyChanged interface as @Erno suggested, if you need this, and bind properties of this type in XAML to your view.

Answer (score 1):

If this is your database model you can easily make a view for join those tables. or you can use this following code as pattern :

```
        var temp = from i in categoryList
                   from it in itemList
                   where i.ItemCategoryID == it.ItemCategoryID 
                   select new { i, it };
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Ya i know that but are there no other way through code? So every different type of view would require a new new database call, a new model, a new function in data logic layer, and business logic layer and so on...

Comment: I have the data on the models can i extend not them some how?

Comment: Thanks but i have found another way.